# Como alterar um dado de uma linha em um dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Nesta função, quero perguntar para o usuário a identificação de um aluno e em seguida mudar seu nome no dataframe. Tentei com o replace(), mas estou fazendo errado.

```
def alterar(df, id_aluno = None, novo_nome = None):
      if id_aluno is not None:
        infos = df.query(f'id_aluno == {id_aluno}')
        return infos
      if novo_nome is None:
        infos = df.replace('Nome = ["novo_nome"]')
        return infos

    id = input("id do aluno: ")
    novo_nome = input("Novo nome: ")
        
    info_alterada = alterar(tabela_alunos_notas, id, novo_nome)
    display(info_alterada)
```

Answer (score -1):

imports e criando o dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

ids = [i for i in range(1, 6)]
nomes = [f'Nome {i}' for i in ids]

tabela_alunos_notas = pd.DataFrame({'id_aluno': ids, 'nome': nomes})

display(tabela_alunos_notas)
```

|  | id_aluno | nome |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | Nome 1 |
| 1 | 2 | Nome 2 |
| 2 | 3 | Nome 3 |
| 3 | 4 | Nome 4 |
| 4 | 5 | Nome 5 |

Recebendo os inputs

```
id_aluno = int(input('Id Aluno: '))
novo_nome = input('Novo nome: ')
```

Na função de alterar você pode utilizar o loc, filtrando pelo id do aluno e atribuindo o novo nome a coluna nome:

```
def alterar(df, id_aluno, novo_nome):
    if id_aluno and novo_nome:
        df.loc[df['id_aluno'] == id_aluno, 'nome'] = novo_nome
```

Chamando a função de alterar o valor:

```
alterar(tabela_alunos_notas, id_aluno, novo_nome)
```

Mostrando o dataframe atualizado:

```
display(tabela_alunos_notas)
```

|  | id_aluno | nome |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | Novo Nome 1 |
| 1 | 2 | Nome 2 |
| 2 | 3 | Nome 3 |
| 3 | 4 | Nome 4 |
| 4 | 5 | Nome 5 |